# Batch file breaking out with "\AEM was unexpected at this time"

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to perform a check to see if a file exists in a sub-folder in the Program Files or Program Files (x86) directory and every single time, my script breaks out with `\AEM was unexpected at this time.`

Here is my code:

```
:UPGRADECHK
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\AEM Keep Alive Service\AEMKeepAlive.exe" (
SET INSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files\AEM Keep Alive Service
GOTO UPGRADE
)

IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\AEM Keep Alive Service\AEMKeepAlive.exe" (
SET INSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\AEM Keep Alive Service
GOTO UPGRADE
)
```

I've tried using the `%PROGRAMFILES%` and `%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%` system variables and the full path but every time, I get the same error. Running the command with `@Echo On` it seems to be the x86 path it's having issues with. Can anyone suggest why it's failing?

Comment: You need quotes in your set commands

Comment: Really? There not included in any other aspect of my script, when I cann the INSTALLDIR variable, I include the quotes then: `"%INSTALLDIR%"`

Comment: Ignore that, seems it did work. Strange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put quotes around your installation directory paths as there are spaces in the filenames. Same as you did in the exist check. Like so:

```
:UPGRADECHK
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\AEM Keep Alive Service\AEMKeepAlive.exe" (
    SET INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\AEM Keep Alive Service"
    GOTO UPGRADE
)

IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\AEM Keep Alive Service\AEMKeepAlive.exe" (
    SET INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\AEM Keep Alive Service"
    GOTO UPGRADE
)
```

Comment: Thanks, while it worked I don't still quite understand why it did not work as I was setting the value of the INSTALLDIR variable to a path. Variables can have spaces in so it's thrown me a bit. Either way, it works now so thanks. :)

Comment: It's not a problem with the spaces, it's a problem with the closing parenthesis. That closes the block

Comment: On the command line, try typing: `cd C:\Program Files`. It won't work as there's a space in the path, so cd thinks it's being passed two parameters: "C:\Program" and "Files". In order to let an executable know that it's being passed that path as a single command line parameter, it requires quotes.

Comment: @jeb There's no problem with the parentheses. They enclose the statements held within the if construct, of which there are two, so parentheses are required here and they are correct. It's the enclosure of the paths that was wrong. It falls over on the AEM in the first check. Parentheses may cause an issue in the 2nd construct, but that would be corrected by the string enclosure, as given above.

Comment: As @jeb has already stated, the closing paranthesis in the `SET` statement closes the `IF` block which is a parsing error. If you quote the `SET` command, the paranthesis is hidden and the block is closed at the right line.

Comment: Yes, that is also a consequential error due to the lack of quotes, but the solution remains the same :)

Comment: But it's better to use the extended syntax of `set` and move the quotes `set "INSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\AEM Keep Alive Service"`. The first quote is in front of the variable name. The effect is, that the quotes aren't present in the INSTALLDIR variable

Comment: Yes, another valid way of doing it. The result is precisely the same in this context though and achieves the desired result.